# Upgrade to MVC 5 results in System.MethodAccessException from Microsoft.Web.Mvc.Internal.ExpressionHelper.GetTargetActionName

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

After upgrading our solution from MVC 2 to MVC 5, an existing method that uses `ExpressionHelper.GetRouteValuesFromExpression()` from `Microsoft.Web.MVC.Internal` throws the `System.MethodAccessException`:

```
at Microsoft.Web.Mvc.Internal.ExpressionHelper.GetTargetActionName(MethodInfo methodInfo)
at Microsoft.Web.Mvc.Internal.ExpressionHelper.GetRouteValuesFromExpression[TController](Expression`1 action)
```

I've seen a few recommendations to use to the `AllowPartiallyTrustedCallersAttribute`, however this is from one of Microsoft's assemblies and not one of our own. Any ideas?

Comment: Isn't that available in the Mvc5 Futures package?  you might want to try adding that if you haven't already